# Use node.js simplecrawler with Angular2 TypeScript Project

Tags: node.js, angular

Is it possible to use simplecrawler for nodejs with Angluar2 TypeScript project? If so, what's the correct setup?

https://github.com/cgiffard/node-simplecrawler

I've installed the module:

```
npm install simplecrawler --save
```

Declared class Crawler in my typescript service:

```
...
declare var Crawler: any;
@Injectable()
...
```

But creating the Crawler object fails:

```
var crawler = new Crawler('http://www.google.com');
```

With browser console error:

```
crawler.js:10 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

I notice that the following file uses require: node_modules\simplecrawler\lib

```
var FetchQueue      = require("./queue.js"),
    CookieJar       = require("./cookies.js"),
    MetaInfo        = require("../package.json");

var http            = require("http"),
    https           = require("https"),
    EventEmitter    = require("events").EventEmitter,
    uri             = require("urijs"),
    zlib            = require("zlib"),
    util            = require("util"),
    iconv           = require("iconv-lite");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not really sure why you are trying to instantiate your crawler in your Angular2 application, unless you are using Angular2 server side.

Simple crawler is meant to be used server-side not client side.

That being said, I think that you are not instantiating your crawler correctly.

When you do this:

```
var crawler = new Crawler('http://www.google.com');
```

You should have something like this:

```
var Crawler = require("simplecrawler");
var crawler = new Crawler('http://www.google.com');
```

The issue is trying to use the keyword require in your front end Angular2 application.  Again I really don't think you want to do this unless you are making a universal Angular2 app.  But if you insist on doing this, you will need to use an import statement for simplecrawler with typescript, instead of require.

```
import {Crawler} from simplecrawler
var crawler = new Crawler('http://www.google.com');
```

Something like that should work.

Comment: I overlooked that simple crawler is server side.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two ways that you might be able to do this. But first the reason you're running into this issue and the reason TypeScript doesn't complain. TypeScript is only involved in translating/checking that your Types and such can be transpiled into JS without an issue. Where the browser is still left with the work of sorting out the JS files and figuring out what to do (or whatever system you're using to manage the JS modules, I could be wrong and maybe SystemJS could manage it? But I doubt it, as you can see in the code you presented, the "require('http');" that's a node.js module).

Anyway, the two solutions that I can see.

1. Write a http service in node.js that would be the middle man between node.js and your browser running Angular2. So maybe use [Express](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/installing.html) on the server side, then in your Angular2 browser code uses [Http](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html) to call the node.js Express methods you created.
2. This one might not fit your criteria but I'm including it as you asked for possible setups. [Electron](http://electron.atom.io/docs/tutorial/quick-start/), this executable runs literally on top of node.js but is used to render websites but as a native desktop application. This provides a unique way to communicate directly to node.js from your js code. There are a few GitHub [barebone](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=Electron%20Angular%202) setups that you could pull down and use as a starting point. Once you have Electron in a running state all you have to do is add this line to your index.html file.

`var Crawler = require("simplecrawler");`

Then you can access the Crawler object inside your .TS files with this

```
var crawler = new window["Crawler"]('http://www.google.com');
```